# Upwards directed sets of measurable functions and its supremum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let (X,$\Lambda$,$\mu$) be a measure space such that $\mu(X)$ is finite and let $M^r=M^r(X,\mu)$ be the set of all real $\mu$ almost everywhere finite valued $\mu$-measurable functions on $X$ with identification of $\mu$-almost equal functions.

Assume $(f_t:t\in T)$ is an ***upwards directed set*** of positive elements of $M^r(X,\mu)$ with the upper bound $g$, i.e., $0\leq f_t\uparrow\leq g$.

For $P=\sup\{\int_Xf_td\mu:t\in T\}$, we can choose an increasing sequence $(f_{_{t_n}}:n\in \Bbb{N})$ in the set $(f_t:t\in T)$ such that 
$$\int_X f_{_{t_n}}d\mu\uparrow P, \text{as}\hspace{0.5cm} n\rightarrow \infty.$$

The pointwise supremum $F(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{_{t_n}}(x)$ is then a $\mu$-measurable function and $$\int_XFd\mu=P.$$

---

Now here is my question,

***Question***: How can we show that for every $t\in T$, 
$$f_t(x)\leq F(x),$$
for almost every $x$ in $X$ and therefore $F(x)=\sup(f_t(x):t\in T)$ in $M^r(X,\mu)$?

---

Many thanks

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true? Consider for instance $T=\{1,2\}$, $\mu$ Lebesgue measure on $X=(0,1)$ and $$f_1(x) := 2 \cdot 1_{(0,1/8)}(x) \quad f_2(x) := 1$$ Then $F(x)=f_2(x)$ but $f_1(x) \leq F_2(x)$ does **not** hold true for $x\in (0,1/8)$ (which  is clearly not a null set).

Comment: (There is a typo in my comment; it should read "[...] but $f_1(x) \leq F(x)$ does not hold true for $x\in (0,1/8)$".)